# Making webView text right size but also preserve <img> size?

Tags: html, css, ios, wkwebview

I'm loading WKWebView (iOS) inside my app and adding some tags to make loaded string looks normally. Here is an example

```swift
htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'><body style=\"margin:0; text-size-adjust: 100%; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;!important\">" + (self.marker?.storeAccess ?? "") + "</body></html>"
```

where `self.marker?.storeAccess` are my data.

I [read](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9003) at many forums that this line `initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0` will make my text "normal-sized", because originally it was too small to even read. And that's good, it works. But it also causing `<img>` to overflow my `webView` and become cut in right-half. I wonder if there is a way to satisfy both `text-size` and `img-width` ?

I tried stuffs like

```html
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

and it didn't work.